# Cannot see nautilus scripts submenu and consequently any scripts installed Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, scripts, nautilus

I am a new Linux user and am running Ubuntu 18.04. I have written a script (the code below). I have called the file "Extract Delete.sh" and have made it executable. It is currently located in /usr/share/nautilus-scripts . I have visited the scripts directory through nautilus as per instructions found here ( (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto?action=show&redirect=Nautilus_Scripts)

I can see the script with the nautilus script manager, however I when I right-click a file in nautilus I cannot see the scripts submenu. I have also created a dummy .sh file in the directory that has no code to run and it also appears in nautilus script manager however not when I right click a file.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Nautilus script to extract an archive and then delete the archive.

IFS='
'
for item in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS; do
if [ -n "$(file -b "$item" | grep -o 'zip' || grep -o '7z' || grep -o 'xz' || grep -o 'bz2' || grep -o 'gz' || grep -o 'tar' || grep -o 'wim')" ]; then

    7z e "$item" && trash "$item"
    # use trash instead of rm to move them to trash
    # (trash-cli package installed)
fi
done
```

Comment: Usually Nautilus scripts go into `   ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/ `  directory, I've never heard of them being placed in `/usr/share/nautilus-scripts`. It may have been up unti developers changed something, but in my own experience only per-user folders work

Comment: Worked! Thank you! It was the nautilus script manager that told me to use that directory...

Comment: Very well. I've converted that into an answer. Congrats on resolving the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As resolved in the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093622/cannot-see-nautilus-scripts-submenu-and-consequently-any-scripts-installed-ubunt?noredirect=1#comment1800608_1093622) and [confirmed by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093622/cannot-see-nautilus-scripts-submenu-and-consequently-any-scripts-installed-ubunt?noredirect=1#comment1800639_1093622):

Usually Nautilus scripts go into `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/` directory, I've never heard of them being placed in /usr/share/nautilus-scripts. It may have been up unti developers changed something, but in my own experience only per-user folders work

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.10 I do not get a "scripts" submenu in the contextual menu after placing scripts in ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts. I have set the scripts to executable, and I have visited that directory in nautilus.

Comment: @Lexible It may be worth asking a question about it on the site, as this is unusual and the directory has been the standard place for storing Nautilus scripts for very long time. Currently I don't have access to 18.10 to test. It potentially may have something to do with the announcement to remove ability to launch binaries and executable scripts for security reasons, see [article on the topic](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/nautilus-remove-ability-launch-binaries-apps).